# Is it possible that multiple devices (servers) have the same external ip?

Tags: ip

When I check devices' external IP (ipv4) from my home I see the same numbers for my phone and laptop. Imagine these devices are servers, both host different sites, and have 80 ports opened. From which server will a site open for the user? (they write in browser <my-external-ip>:80).

Comment: Unfortunately, questions about home networking and consumer-grade devices are explicitly off-topic here. You could try to ask this question on [su].

Answer (score 1):

> When I check devices' external IP (ipv4) from my home I see the same numbers for my phone and laptop.

That's called *source NAT* - the private IP addresses are translated to a single public IP address (or a small pool) for outgoing requests and back for the replies.

> Imagine these devices are servers, both host different sites, and have 80 ports opened. From which server will a site open for the user? (they write in browser :80).

With the servers themselves running on private addresses, *destination NAT* aka port forwarding aka reverse NAT is required. You can map a TCP port on the public address to a single private address:port only, so you can't map both servers on the same public port. You either need to use two public IP addresses or two public TCP ports or use an application-layer gateway (reverse HTTP proxy).

All this is IPv4, of course. IPv6 doesn't use NAT and you're usually provided with sufficient addresses to host even a larger number of servers.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not in a Multiple NAT enviroment and your router/firewall does not block or forward the port 80, all the the connections on that port goes to your router/firewall.
To forward the connections to different Webservers hosted by servers in your LAN enviroment you should set up a reverse proxy.
In that way you can forward different hostname called via the HTTP protocol on port 80 to different servers.